# Mock Desktop switch/4 finger swipe with a script

Tags: macos, mouse, touchpad, applescript

I have an older Apple wired mouse

It has side buttons, which I'd like to program to use like the **four finger swipe** on the touch pad (the one that switches between desktops).

In mouse settings, there isn't an option for desktop switching. There **is** an option to map an Apple Script file.

How would I make an Apple Script to mock this action?

[image].

Answer (score 0):

This article shows a bunch of the shortcut keys (and how to customize them) for swapping desktops/spaces: http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/06/switch-between-desktops-spaces-faster-in-os-x-with-control-keys/

Seems like Ctrl-Left-Arrow or Ctrl-Right-Arrow might work, so hopefully you can map the mouse button(s) to one or both of those.

If you can't map the buttons to keystrokes, then this AppleScript is supposed to work (lots of sources about this online), but it doesn't work on my Mac.  I think I may not have enabled the "Access for assistive devices" correctly under Sierra that's required for `System Events`.

```
tell application "System Events" to key code 124 using control down
```

Let me know if that AppleScript works for you!

Comment: More testing with variations of that AppleScript show that "key code 124" is indeed the right-arrow (easy to test by scripting the Finder or Excel), and it (sometimes) appears that "control down" is working (sometimes it seems to get stuck down, thus affecting mouse movements/clicks after the script ends).  I think Sierra has significantly neutered a lot of the key codes, as simple things like F11 (Show Desktop) don't work either.